# How do I use HashSet<T> as a dictionary key?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I wish to use `HashSet<T>` as the key to a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<HashSet<T>, TValue> myDictionary = new Dictionary<HashSet<T>, TValue>();
```

I want to look up values from the dictionary such that two different instances of `HashSet<T>` that *contain the same items* will return the same value.

`HashSet<T>`'s implementations of `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` don't seem to do this (I think they're just the defaults). I can override `Equals()` to use `SetEquals()` but what about `GetHashCode()`? I feel like I am missing something here...

Comment: Keep in mind that if you modify a HashSet after you use it as a key, your dictionary could stop working as expected. `As long as an object is used as a key in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value. Every key in a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> must be unique according to the dictionary's equality comparer.` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Comment: Yep, these days an `ImmutableHashSet<T>` would be a better choice!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could use the set comparer provided by `HashSet<T>`:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<HashSet<T>, TValue>(HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer());
```

Comment: didn't know that one existed! looks interesting (and now I feel foolish for writing an answer with a custom one ;p)

Comment: @Marc: eh eh, me neither until Jon Skeet once showed it to me :)

Comment: Of course, I completely forgot that the dictionary uses a comparer too - d'oh! Also I didn't know about that one :)

Comment: Unfortunately, `HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer()` does not seem to exist on .NET Core (yet)

Comment: Warning!! `HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer` will use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`!! http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs I needed a culture sensitive version of this, but unfortunately `HashSetEqualityComparer` which has such a constructor, is internal.

Answer (score 9):

digEmAll's answer is clearly the better choice in practice, since it uses built in code instead of reinventing the wheel. But I'll leave this as a sample implementation.

---

You can use implement an `IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>>` that uses `SetEquals`. Then pass it to the constructor of the Dictionary. Something like the following(Didn't test it):

```
class HashSetEqualityComparer<T>: IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>>
{
    public int GetHashCode(HashSet<T> hashSet)
    {
        if(hashSet == null)
           return 0;
        int h = 0x14345843; //some arbitrary number
        foreach(T elem in hashSet)
        {
            h = unchecked(h + hashSet.Comparer.GetHashCode(elem));
        }
        return h;
    }

    public bool Equals(HashSet<T> set1, HashSet<T> set2)
    {
        if(set1 == set2)
            return true;
        if(set1 == null || set2 == null)
            return false;
        return set1.SetEquals(set2);
    }
}
```

Note that the hash function here is commutative, that's important because the enumeration order of the elements in the set is undefined.

One other interesting point is that you can't just use `elem.GetHashCode` since that will give wrong results when a custom equality comparer was supplied to the set.

Comment: Note that `^` is *generally* a bad idea in hashes, but in this case since we know the values are unique it probably works.

Comment: I chose ^ because it commutes and because the values are unique and thus the x^x=0 problem isn't that relevant. But probably addition is still a better idea.

Comment: I don't know if it is appropriate to ask questions in comments but can you explain or post a link that elaborates on why xor is a bad idea in hashes? I thought that it was a good idea as long as the values participating in the hashing was also part of the equality comparison. Thanks!

Comment: One reason why xor is bad is because duplicates cancel out. x^x=0 for all x. So for example you have a 2d vector, and use hashfunction `X^Y` every vector with `X==Y` will collide. And the fact that xor is commutative means that swapping the value of properties will give collisions too. e.g. `X=1,Y=5` collides with `X=5,Y=1`

Comment: @faester @CodeInChaos: Meanwhile using `+` doesn't guarantee the hash code to be unique either, all `X == -Y` instances get the same hash code. But anyway `+` is better than `^`, both are correct. The one who  has less probability to get a same code from two different objects is better.

Comment: A unique hash can only be guaranteed in a few cases. But yes both + and ^ are usually bad choices to combine hashes. But I chose them in this case because they are commutative. The common choices to combine hashes(like `hash=hash*primeConstant+elemHash`) are non commutative by design. And here commutative combining is required. Btw the MS implementation uses `^`

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Thanks! -- I have seen the `^` at MS implementation why I got confused. But thanks for a the explanation.

Comment: Onj .NET Core, you apparently have to create your own comparer, so thank you for this example implementation

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a `IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>>` to the Dictionary constructor and make the desired implementation in that comparer.