# Subclass HashSet so that it always uses a certain IEqualityComparer when used in another set

Tags: c#, .net, hashset, iequalitycomparer

I want to subclass `HashSet<Point>` so that it uses `HashSet<Point>.CreateSetComparer()` as an `IEqualityComparer` whenever I use it inside another set.

Basically every time I do this:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<MySubclassOfHashSet, Char>();
```

I want it  automatically treated as :

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<HashSet<Point>, Char>(HashSet<Point>.CreateSetComparer());
```

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910137/how-do-i-use-hashsett-as-a-dictionary-key).

I have currently done this manually as follows:

```
class MySubclassOfHashSet: HashSet<Point> {
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
      //...
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
      //...
    }
}
```

But it's kind of ugly. Is there an easier way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var myDict = new Dictionary<MySubclassOfHashSet<Point>, Char>();

    public sealed class MySubclassOfHashSet<T> : HashSet<T>, IEquatable<MySubclassOfHashSet<T>>
    {
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Unique.GetHashCode(this);
        }
        public bool Equals(MySubclassOfHashSet<T> other)
        {
            return Unique.Equals(this, other);
        }

        private static readonly IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>> Unique = HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer();
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also implement `public override bool Equals(object obj)`? And add annoyingly any parameterized constructors from `HashSet<T>`