# Pragma to disable warning causing another warning (CS1692)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, warnings, pragma

I've the following snippet of code in one of my C# classes:

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5910237

        if (set == null) return 0;

        int h = 0x14345843;

        foreach (T elem in set)
        {
            h = unchecked(h + set.Comparer.GetHashCode(elem));
        }

        return h;
    }
```

With this code, I'll receive a warning: "Non-readonly field referenced in 'GetHashCode()'".

As that is intended in this case, I added the following pragma to dismiss that warning: `#pragma warning disable RECS0025`.

However, after adding that pragma, I received a new warning **only in the Unity Editor - not when building the code in Visual Studio**:

> warning CS1692: Invalid number

Double-clicking it would take me straight to that `#pragma warning disable RECS0025` line.

What am I doing wrong here? The goal is to suppress the RECS0025 warning, of course without causing another warning.

**Extra:** I tried disabling the CS1692 warning around the RECS0025 pragmas, but that didn't work either; the CS1692 error continued occurring.

**Extra extra:** I've some code elsewhere as follows:

```
#pragma warning disable RECS0108
    static SharedPool<Tuple<HierarchyMember, string>, ReactiveProperty<T>> _sharedPool;
#pragma warning restore RECS0108
```

This does **not** cause the CS1692 error to occur. That is, if I remove the `#pragma warning disable RECS0025` from around the `GetHashCode` function, but leave the above `RECS0108` pragma in, there will be no `CS1692` warning.

Not sure how this adds up with the two provided answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to the non-numeric prefix.  I'm guessing Unity is using an old compiler or not the most recent spec of C#?  I'm not familiar with the Unity compiler at all, but this should fix it.

Be aware this disables all warnings, so I'd limit it in scope as much as possible.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5910237
#pragma warning disable
    if (set == null) return 0;

    int h = 0x14345843;

    foreach (T elem in set)
    {
        h = unchecked(h + set.Comparer.GetHashCode(elem));
    }

    return h;
#pragma warning restore
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I ended up going with this solution. To minimise the scope I instantiated a new variable `var s = set;` (and used that instead of `set` elsewhere), and disabled warnings for only that line of declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Before C# 6, you aren't allowed to use prefixes on `pragma` instructions - everything is assumed to be intended for the C# compiler.

So to take your C# example:

```
#pragma warning CS1692
```

and

```
#pragma warning 1692
```

are equivalent, but the first one is not valid until C# 6. Unfortunately, Unity uses an older compiler. There is no way of specifying `RECS0025` in source code without that. Options:

- fix the error - presumably by calculating the hashcode at construction and asserting that the set contents cannot ever change (it should be a read-only set 
  *anyway* to be used in this way)
- ignore the error visually
- find another way to suppress that warning
- disable the tool that is raising the warning

I'd go with the first one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It makes sense, but I've added an **extra extra** to my answer which... doesn't add up. What do you think?